# ruby lazy private method

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, activemodel, ruby-2.0

I have a class:

```
class Validator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless valid?(value)
      record.errors.add(attribute, attribute.to_sym, options.merge(value: value))
    end
  end
end
```

And I have a huge amount of subclasses(with just private `valid?` method), i.e

```
class KppValidator < Validator
  private

  def valid?(kpp)
    kpp.size == 9
  end
end
```

Is there any way to avoid writing `private` before each valid? method in descendant classes?

I tried to write 'private :valid?', in class Validator, but got an exception `no such method 'valid?'`

What I can do?

Comment: That seems like a perfectly reasonable method to just make public...

Comment: Why so? I'll never do something like `KppValidator.valid?(kpp)`

Comment: If you have a list of all the methods you want to make private, you could use [Module#private](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-private) (with its argument a method)  to run through the list to make them all private.

Comment: @muistooshort, but it makes project very DRY. I wish to use about 10 same validators for my gem.

It can remove about 70LOC from my lib

Comment: A class should not exist if it has no public interface. You should either make `valid?` public or not have the class. If you feel the method shouldn't be public but also feel you need the class, you likely are reaching for the wrong design pattern.

Comment: @AlexPeachey, I write a gem with huge (about 10) amount of validators. Do you think I need to write these lines at each validators?

I think this pattern is bad

Comment: @muistooshort, but **why** I can't avoid this superfluous line, if my library will be about 400LOC? Why I need else 20% of code?

Comment: @asiniy, first that's not huge, but more importantly, I didn't say you should write those methods and those classes, you decided that. All I said was that they shouldn't be private. If you feel having a bunch of small subclasses with a single public method is a bad idea then don't do it that way.

Comment: @AlexPeachey, can you offer other way to unify validators?

Comment: With just the code given I can't offer a better way. Without the context of why you are even validating in this fashion and use cases, it is difficult to look for a better way of solving the problem. As currently laid out the issue is you have a validator that you want to subclass with the only thing changing being how to determine if the value parameter is valid. In a vacuum I don't see a huge problem with your solution to that specific problem other than `valid?` should be public. But it could well be there is a better solution depending on your usage and the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your whole approach is a bit odd in the Ruby context. A more Rubyish and Railsy approach would be to write a macro and then use a block in your subclasses rather than a private method.

Something like this:

```
class Validator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def self.validate_using(&block)
    define_method :validate_each do |record, attribute, value|
      unless block[value]
        record.errors.add(attribute, attribute.to_sym, options.merge(value: value))
      end
    end
  end
end

class KppValidator < Validator
  validate_using { |kpp| kpp.size == 9 }
end
```

Since this defines the whole `validate_each` method, this even saves you a method call during validation (at the minor expense of a bit of extra work while initializing everything).

I don't know if this is worthwhile for just ten validators, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Yes, this would work well and it is both DRY and doesn't leave all those poor subclasses with nothing public.

Comment: @Alex: But more importantly, it is a nice simple exercise in metaprogramming and that's a useful tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: @muistooshort, it seems good! Did I unerstood right, that I need block return true?

Comment: The block would return the same that your `valid?` method would. So yes, it would need to return a true value if everything was okay.

Comment: It works, but with little changes :-)

My gem: https://github.com/asiniy/validates_russian

Thanks for you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Writing `private` on its own can be inconvenient if you want to shift back to `public` for subsequent methods. Instead you could try:

```
class KppValidator < Validator
  def valid?(kpp)
    kpp.size == 9
  end
  private :valid?
end
```

As of Ruby 2.1.0 `def` returns the method name as a symbol, so you can streamline this as:

```
class KppValidator < Validator
  private def valid?(kpp)
    kpp.size == 9
  end
end
```

But you're right, even if you were to define `valid?` as a private method in the base class, it will become public in the subclass when you redefine it unless you explicitly make it private.